# How to draw a sprite with NSImage?

Tags: cocoa, nsimage, sprite

I am trying to draw a sprite with NSImage using the drawInRect method.  I noticed quickly that the coordinates passed in the rects are not in pixels but in points.  I need to draw my sprites with pixel level accuracy, as each sprite is say exactly 73x92 pixels in dimensions.

In short, it seems I need either one of the following:
1) NSImage to accept my rects that are in pixels not some other unit.
2) a very accurate conversion from pixel to NSImage units such that addressing a pixel will not lead to any blurriness due to anti-aliasing effects.

Comment: Why not just break each image out into a separate image?

Comment: You will have to give us an example, maybe with example images, you could be suffering from some antialiasing due to 75/72 dpi conversions...

Comment: I'm with Peter. Why bother mucking about with sprite sheets when you can just load the images individually? I understand on iOS/OpenGL this can improve performance but the Mac is so much more powerful there is really very little need to use sprite sheets.

Comment: I should add a disclaimer that I'm not a game developer, so I'm prepared to be called wrong on this one…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with NSImage that would make that impossible. If you give it appropriate source and destination rects, it can certainly draw with pixel-level accuracy. You'll have to post your code for us to help in that regard.

However, you may find it easier to deal with a lower-level API. NSImage is designed to work with anything that seems like an image -- bitmaps, PDFs, etc. That generality, and its age, leads to some confusing behavior sometimes. I've found that using CGImage (which is always a bitmap) can be a lot more predictable. Or, try NSBitmapImageRep.

Comment: It's also important to note that Pixels Per Inch matters with `NSImage`. `NSImage` will respect the PPI of the source image file and draw it appropriately. If your source image is not 72ppi then it will be drawn using antialiasing, as Grady Player pointed out. Both `CGImage` and `NSBitmapImageRep` are purely bitmap formats where the use of ppi doesn't make sense.